# NET Memory Management: FORMCLOSED handled by owned UserControl

Tags: memory-management

When a UserControl is listening for the FORMCLOSED event raised by its owner form, does the UserControl need to call RemoveHandler as part of handling the Form's event in order to assure that both the Form and the UserControl will be GC'd properly?